# How to link my HTML form to a view class in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

**post_form.Html**

This is an Html Page With Form to Update and Create As We Know that Create And Update View Class in Django used the same form

```html
     <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="PostInput">PostTitle</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="post" placeholder="Name" value="{{ post.postname }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="descrInput">Description</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="descrInput" placeholder="Description" value="{{ post.description }}">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

**Views.py**

```
class CreatePost(CreateView):
    model = post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

class UpdatePost(UpdateView):
    model = post
    fields = ['title', 'content']
```

Now, the question is how can i link this form with the above html page which **already has form or input fields** in the web page itself. I know how to do it using function views but i am not getting any materials, tutorials anything about this. Any Material regarding this will be helpful

Comment: There is not forms.py there is an HTML form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override [**`CreateView().post()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.BaseCreateView.post) and [**`UpdateView().post()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.BaseUpdateView.post) methods like this

```
class CreatePost(CreateView):
    model = post
    fields = ['title', 'content']
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get your data from post request eg. request.POST['mykey']
        return redirect('success_page')
```

---

```
class UpdatePost(UpdateView):
    model = post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get your data from post request eg. request.POST['mykey']
        return redirect('success_page')
```

**Note** : You've created your post model class in lowercase which is not good practice always name a class in [**CapWords**](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names). Because you have written your class in lowercase python will treat your post class as a post method or it may lead to logical error.